# Why does it respect group structure?

Tags: group-theory

Assume $f: GL_2(A) \to S_3$ where $A = \{0,1\}$.

Why does it satisfy $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$?

My thought: Take a = $\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{matrix}\right) $   and   $b = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$.  Then $ab = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right) $.

Then $ab$ is not even in $GL_2(A)$. How come does this map respect group structure?

$Edit:$

Assume $f: GL_2(A) \to S_3$ where $A = \{0,1\}$.
Define $f$ so that it's a bijection. So $f$ can be anything as long as it's bijective.  It's possible because the order of $GL_2(A)$ and $S_3$ are the same which is 6.

I want to prove that $f(ab) = f(a)*f(b)$.

My initial thought was to take some examples and show it works but I don't think that's enough.
So the second idea I found is to use a generator. So I want to prove the homomorphism of $f$ using a generator, but I don't know how to use it exactly.

My thought is:
Let $g, h$ be generators of $GL_2(A)$ and $S_3$ individually.

Take $a,b \in GL_2(A)$.  Then I can say $a = g^m$  and $b = g^n$ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ , and m $\neq$ n.
Then $f(ab) = f(g^n * g^m)$.
I'm stuck at this point. Should I use the fact that $f$ is bijective somehow?

$Update:$
An idea came to me that:
I can define $f$ such that $f(g) = h, f(g^2) = h^2, ... f(g^m) = h^m$ where $g^m = e$ and $h^m = e'$. Note that $e \in GL_2(A), e' \in S_3$.

Now take $a, b \in GL_2(A)$ where $a = g^m, b = g^n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $f(a)f(b) = f(g^m)f(g^n) = h^m * h^n = h^{m+n} = f(g^{m+n}) = f(ab)$.

Does this work?
I just noticed that $GL_2(A)$ doesn't have a generator..
I don't the idea works.

Update: I found that both groups have a generator set with 2 elements. Can I use this somehow?

Edit: The following is my original problem
[image]

Comment: 1) What is $f$? 2) I guess that your $A$ is the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In this case, the (1,2)-entry of $ab$ is $0$ since $1+1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Hence $ab$ is still in $GL_2(A)$.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the map? Everything you ask about is taking place on the left side anyway (and that part is answered in the comment of Alan above).

Comment: f is just a label. And a,b are actions of the group $GL_2(A)$.  oh so I shouldn't simply do matrix multiplication? I need to use $\mathbb{Z}_2$..

Comment: @jun Yes $f$ is a label representing a function, but presumably it represents a *specific* function. For example, it could represent the function where every element is mapped to the identity of $S_3$, and then it would satisfy your property. On the other hand, it could represent the function which send every matrix to the identity of $S_3$, apart from the identity matrix which is mapped to $(123)$, but then this function does not satisfy your property. So more information is needed.

Comment: Where did this question come from, and how is it phrased *precisely*? With your edit the question kind of makes sense, but there is still an issue: asking "Why does it satisfy..." implies that these maps $f$ *do* satisfy this in general, but they don't.

Comment: As in other comments: I'd wager that you've accidentally lost some hypotheses. The desired conclusion certainly does not hold for _all_ bijections $f$.

Comment: Okay, adding the image has made it clear. You have an arbitrary bijection between the *vector space* (which your linear group acts on) and the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ (which $S_3$ acts on), rather than between the groups. (Your question is now better, but it would be nicer if you could reorder it to make it a single question - having edits at the bottom which add more detail make the question hard to read/follow.)